# Sql code not working while trying to create a new function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a new function in SQL with the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION PROFITIBLE_CATEGORIES (@startDate date, @endDate date)
RETURNS @ResultTable TABLE (Name varchar(20), AMOUNT INT)
AS BEGIN
    @ResultTable =  SELECT TOP 5 NAME, COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT
                    FROM dbo.PURCHASES P JOIN 
                        (SELECT PInC.NAME, PInC.[Walmart number],
                                 PInSP.[Purchase Id] AS PInSP_PURCHASE_ID,
                                 DPP.[Purchase Id] AS DPP_PURCHASE_ID

                         FROM dbo.PRODUCTS_IN_CATEGORIES PInC LEFT JOIN 
                         dbo.Products_in_self_pick_up_purchases PInSP ON 
                         PInC.[Walmart number] = PInSP.[Walmart number] LEFT JOIN
                         dbo.Delivered_products_purchases DPP ON 
                         DPP.[Walmart number] = PInC.[Walmart number]) X
                         ON (P.[Purchase Id] = X.DPP_PURCHASE_ID) 
                         OR (P.[Purchase Id] = X.PInSP_PURCHASE_ID)
                    WHERE [Date] < @endDate AND [Date] > @startDate
                    GROUP BY NAME
                    ORDER BY AMOUNT
    RETURN 
    END
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PROFITIBLE_CATEGORIES, Line 4
>   
> Incorrect syntax near '@ResultTable'.

anyone can help?
It's probably a syntax error, but I'm new to this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at both answers? Just curious why you would choose a less efficient approach. I don't care about the reputation but I do care about the best answer being selected - both for you and for future readers.

Comment: I changed my selection for future readers. 
The reason I selected otherwise was that this is for a course at the university, and we haven't learned inline functions, so I can't use it.
but you are right. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly more efficient approach would be an inline table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PROFITIBLE_CATEGORIES
(
  @startDate date, 
  @endDate date
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN 
    (
       SELECT TOP (5) NAME, COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT
       FROM dbo.PURCHASES P JOIN 
                       (SELECT PInC.NAME, PInC.[Walmart number],
                                 PInSP.[Purchase Id] AS PInSP_PURCHASE_ID,
                                 DPP.[Purchase Id] AS DPP_PURCHASE_ID

                         FROM dbo.PRODUCTS_IN_CATEGORIES PInC LEFT JOIN 
                         dbo.Products_in_self_pick_up_purchases PInSP ON 
                         PInC.[Walmart number] = PInSP.[Walmart number] LEFT JOIN
                         dbo.Delivered_products_purchases DPP ON 
                         DPP.[Walmart number] = PInC.[Walmart number]) X
                         ON (P.[Purchase Id] = X.DPP_PURCHASE_ID) 
                         OR (P.[Purchase Id] = X.PInSP_PURCHASE_ID)
                    WHERE [Date] < @endDate AND [Date] > @startDate
                    GROUP BY NAME
                    ORDER BY AMOUNT
    );
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are inserting rows to your table then try this

```
   CREATE FUNCTION PROFITIBLE_CATEGORIES (@startDate date, @endDate date)
   RETURNS @ResultTable TABLE (Name varchar(20), AMOUNT INT)
   AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ResultTable
    SELECT TOP 5 NAME, COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT
                FROM dbo.PURCHASES P JOIN 
                    (SELECT PInC.NAME, PInC.[Walmart number],
                             PInSP.[Purchase Id] AS PInSP_PURCHASE_ID,
                             DPP.[Purchase Id] AS DPP_PURCHASE_ID

                     FROM dbo.PRODUCTS_IN_CATEGORIES PInC LEFT JOIN 
                     dbo.Products_in_self_pick_up_purchases PInSP ON 
                     PInC.[Walmart number] = PInSP.[Walmart number] LEFT JOIN
                     dbo.Delivered_products_purchases DPP ON 
                     DPP.[Walmart number] = PInC.[Walmart number]) X
                     ON (P.[Purchase Id] = X.DPP_PURCHASE_ID) OR (P.[Purchase Id] = X.PInSP_PURCHASE_ID)
                WHERE [Date] < @endDate AND [Date] > @startDate
                GROUP BY NAME
                ORDER BY AMOUNT
RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Please don't forget to use the schema prefix on the function name.

Comment: You should make it an inline table function though... those are more efficient overall.

Comment: amazing! thank you very much! it worked. I'd vote up for you but I don't have enough credit yet :)

Comment: Inner tables are more efficient try @Aaron Bertrand suggested.